# Special characters on MFC dialog form

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I can see special characters `ąęį` when I do form design on static text label:

[image]

These character are changed while running:

[image]

If I set these characters in programming way I have:

[image]

How can I ensure that the correct characters are displayed instead of question marks as shown in the screenshot above?

UPD:

My project is Multi-Byte. I found that in another computer I can see special characters. Why?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use Unicode character set for this to work correctly, and my guess is that you're using MBCS character set now.

You could change it in the project properties. Refer to this screenshot:[image]

Visual studio editor is fully Unicode, meaning it could display such special characters as you type when you're designing the dialog. However, if your application is not built with Unicode support, it won't be able to display thsoe characters when it runs. Thich is why you see the ??? replacing the Unicode text when you run the application.

Comment: Yes, my project is Multi-Byte, but I prefer not change this since I have many compile errors while doing that. I found that in another computer I can see special characters. Why?

Comment: I understand you may be running into some issues while porting to Unicode, but feel free to seek help here to resolve those. Here's a guide which might get you started: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc194801.aspx

Comment: If you don't want to change the project to Unicode then put `::SetDlgItemTextW(m_hWnd, IDC_STATIC_X, L"ąęį")` inside the *.cpp code, as a patch...

Answer (score 0):

If you get different results on different computers this is obviously due to differences in system settings.

The setting that controls this is called "Language for non-Unicode programs", and can be found under Control Panel, Language, Change date, time or number formats. Unfortunately it's a global setting (ie cannot be set per application or programmatically) and requires a re-boot.

Consider making your application Unicode, if possible (and meaningful cost- or effort-wise).